# How much time It takes to perform all tests using Android CTS tool?

Tags: android, android-emulator, cts

I am developing **custom android device** and need to execute compatibility test cases using android `CTS tool`.

So i just want to know how much time it will take to execute all the test cases on the `android device(Android Emulator)` using **android-cts-2.3_r3-x86 tool**.

Answer (score 1):

The time for execution of CTS depends upon the total number of test cases and each status of the test case result. To pass a test the result must come in 5 seconds for most of test cases, otherwise the test cases is timed out. After each time out there is a gap of 5 minutes to execute next test case by CTS. So it is directly proportional to the number of timed out test cases. Many time the devices restarts, so the restart time is also counted. Now you can calculate the estimated time of CTS execution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is displayed an estimation at the beginning of the tests, like in the above example:

```
255522-06-07 14:32:23 I/CompatibilityTest: ========================================
255599:06-07 14:32:23 I/CompatibilityTest: Starting a run with 362 unique modules.
255675-06-07 14:32:23 I/CompatibilityTest: ========================================
255752-06-07 14:32:23 I/ModuleRepo: 10.10.1.113:5555 running 362 test sub-modules, expected to complete in 86h 46m 18s.
```

if you lost that is not a problem you can always check the logs with the command in `cts-tf >` cursor:

```
d l
```

shortcut for `dump logs` will output:

```
Saved log to /tmp/Invocation-134.86.122.113:5555_log_7887452889537372588.txt
Saved log to /tmp/tradefed_history_log_6569426154219158581.txt
Saved log to /tmp/tradefed_global_log_802202482888218382.txt
```

and then grep in the logs for unique and 2 lines:

```
cat ./Invocation-134.86.122.113:5555_log_3749453462240679705.txt | grep unique -b2
```

Answer (score -1):

This took me almost exactly 2 hours to run the full test set on a SHIELD.  The results of tests:
- PASSED: 9805
- FAILED: 7
- NOT EXECUTED: 8977