# How to know the total test case count in android CTS

Tags: android, cts

I am running CTS8.1_r4 for my product. is there any command or way to know total available test cases/ module  or for complete cts package?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have not found any way to see how many test are other than running all the modules, and then run

```
l r
```

command and check the last session where the test were completed and add column 2 and 3.

Running the entire cts suite takes some time and sometimes it stops to see how much it take to run and how to continue by running only the failed and the ones that weren't execute check this answers:

[How much time It takes to perform all tests using Android CTS tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911535/how-much-time-it-takes-to-perform-all-tests-using-android-cts-tool/50857668#50857668)

[When I run CTS after a few hours the adb connection to device becomes unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602901/when-i-run-cts-after-a-few-hours-the-adb-connection-to-device-becomes-unresponsi/50857094#50857094)

Comment: My Question was different -- How to get to know the total no of test cases present in CTS package.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation (`cts-tradefed run commandAndExit cts-dev --help-all`) I have found the `--collect-tests-only` option which should help.

The following command lists all the **enabled** tests without running them:

```
cts-tradefed run commandAndExit cts-dev --collect-tests-only
```

and it can be done per-module or per-test too:

```
cts-tradefed run commandAndExit cts-dev --collect-tests-only --module CtsMediaTestCases
```

This still requires a device reachable via `adb` because it actually uploads and lists the tests on the device, so listing the test of the complete cts package may still take a while.